# How to read a local text file in cordova?

Tags: javascript, html, file, line

I am currently working on a html5 app and for this I need to access a .txt file which is storing variables. These variables need to be accessed inside a javascript file thats stored outside the index.html.

e.g.

```
daysInWeek = 5
```

How can I read in my text file? Each variable is stored on a new line and I need the file to be read when the app loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place your file inside your www folder and make a http request to load it from your application. 
This would return the contents of the file and then you could process it the way you want. 
Anyway, I would use a JSON file instead of a text file.

Example for a file located inside www/JSON, using angularjs $http service:

```
$http.get('json/myfile.json').then( function(response){ 
    var data = response.data;
    //do your processing in here
}, function(error){ 
    console.log("Error opening local resource ");
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i unfortunately get this error: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: $http is not defined at script.js:5
(anonymous) @ script.js:5
Any idea what the problem is much appreciated

Comment: @JordanWilliams It depends on which technologies you are using. I just gave you an example on how it could be done with AngularJS. What technologies are you using?